# arch/arm64/Makefile:27: ld does not support --fix-cortex-a53-843419; kernel may be susceptible to erratum

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kernel, cross-compiling

I have tried to compile a custom kernel based on this source: https://github.com/dlwlrma123/kernel_poco_citrus

So, I have to get stuck with this error :

```
arch/arm64/Makefile:27: ld does not support --fix-cortex-a53-843419; kernel may be susceptible to erratum
make: *** No rule to make target '–j4'.  Stop.
```

What I have done:

navigate to the source folder and run `make distclean`

After that, `make gki_defconfig`

I have installed a toolchain in this path: `/opt/arm/9/toolchain` so I have run this command to build this kernel:

```
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/arm/9/toolchain/bin/arm-none-eabi- –j4
```

And the following error is prohibited me from compiling this kernel:

```
arch/arm64/Makefile:27: ld does not support --fix-cortex-a53-843419; kernel may be susceptible to erratum
make: *** No rule to make target '–j4'.  Stop.
```

I am completely a noob in kernel development, I understand something wrong with `$SOURCE_DIR/arch/arm64/Makefile at line 27` I need your help to pass this problem.

Thanks for reading this properly.

Comment: "And the following error is prohibited me from compiling this kernel" - No, you have incorrectly interpreted the output. The line with "ld does not support" is just a **warning**, it doesn't prevent the kernel to be compiled. What prevents the compilation is `–j4` option, which is incorrect spelling of proper `-j4`. Probably, you have copy-pasted your command line from some web-page, which replaces dash (`-`) with a non-ASCII character.

Comment: Thanks. I will try again to see if everything is fine. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Tsyvarev please see a new error, as I have typed my command properly and it somewhat compiles. can you check this log here: https://pastebin.com/vqVB9ncf

Comment: Errors in the log looks like a configuration problem. If you want us to help with them, you need to paste them into the **question post**. This is how Stack Overflow works. See also [ask].